# find NaN values is cell array

Tags: matlab, cells

lets assume I have the following array:

```
a = {1; 'abc'; NaN}
```

Now I want to find out in which indices this contains NaN, so that I can replace these with '' (empty string).

If I use `cellfun` with `isnan` I get a useless output

```
cellfun(@isnan, a, 'UniformOutput', false)

ans = 
[          0]
[1x3 logical]
[          1]
```

So how would I do this correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Indeed, as you found yourself, this can be done by

```
a(cellfun(@(x) any(isnan(x)),a)) = {''}
```

Breakdown:

```
Fx = @(x) any(isnan(x))
```

will return a *logical scalar*, irrespective of whether `x` is a scalar or vector. 
Using this function inside `cellfun` will then erradicate the need for `'UniformOutput', false`:

```
>> inds = cellfun(Fx,a)
inds =
     0
     0
     1
```

These can be used as indices to the original array:

```
>> a(inds)
ans = 
    [NaN]
```

which in turn allows assignment to these indices:

```
>> a(inds) = {''}
a = 
    [1]
    'abc'
    ''
```

Note that the assignment must be done to a cell array itself. If you don't understand this, read up on the differences between `a(inds)` and `a{inds}`.

Comment: If `x` is a matrix, you need to alter the anonymous function to `@(x) any(any(isnan(x)))` (i.e. add `any` for the second time, to ensure you get a scalar from the function)).

Comment: @peci1: you're right. Actually, more generally, it would be best to do `any(isnan(x(:))`, which works for arrays of any dimension and calls `any` only once.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer on http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/42273

```
a(cellfun(@(x) any(isnan(x)),a)) = {''}
```

However, I do not understant it...

Answer (score 2):

- `a(ind) = []` will remove the entries from the array
- `a(ind)= {''}` will replace the `NaN` with an empty string.

If you want to delete the entry use `= []` instead of `= {''}`.
If you wanted to replace the `NaN`s with a different value just set it equal to that value using curly braces:

```
a(ind) = {value}
```